# Django Forms and Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a function based view:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = IngredientForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        ingredient_1 = form.cleaned_data['ingredient_1']
        ingredient_2 = form.cleaned_data['ingredient_2']
        ingredient_3 = form.cleaned_data['ingredient_3']
        ingredient_4 = form.cleaned_data['ingredient_4']
        ingredient_5 = form.cleaned_data['ingredient_5']
        messages.success(request, f'Ingredients added to your account!')
        return redirect('profile')
else:
    form = IngredientForm(user=request.user)
return render(request, 'users/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

and the model is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ingredients(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
ingredient_1 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
ingredient_2 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
ingredient_3 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
ingredient_4 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
ingredient_5 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

forms.py looks like:

```
class IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(IngredientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
class Meta:
    model = ingredients
    fields = ('ingredient_1', 'ingredient_2', 'ingredient_3', 'ingredient_4', 'ingredient_5')
```

I am trying to get the current user and use that as the key for the ingredients table in my database. I am not sure how to get the current user and set the user in the table as the current user. Any help would be appreciated :)

The error that I get when I submit the form is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The user field in ingredients is a primary key, so it has a not null constraint.
The moment you call  `form.save()`, django tries to create a new instance of ingredients from the data bound to the form and user is not bound to it, so it fails because it cannot create a new instance with user=None. The following should work:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.user = request.user 
instance.save()
```

Alternatively, you could overwrite the form's save method.

Edit: I understand now (I think) what you want to do. You want to extend the User model by a 'User Profile'. Here is how you would do that: adjust your ingredients model by the following UserIngredients model (I delete the primary_key argument and added related_name):

```
class UserIngredients(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ingredients')
    ingredient_1 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ...
```

You can connect the creation/update of a User instance with creation/update of a UserIngredients instance via signals as follows: We need one import:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
```

Then add the following to your models file:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserIngredients.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.ingredients.save()
```

In the end, omit the overwriting of the `__init__` of the IngredientForm and adjust your profile method:

```
form = IngredientForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instance.save()
    messages.success(request, f'Ingredients added to your account!')
    return redirect('profile')
```

Comment: Apart from that, your model design seems a bit flawd (a table Ingredients with fields also called ingredient..) - if you could shortly describe what you are modelling, maybe someone could suggest alternative models. A model in django corresponds to a database table and a table corresponds to a noun(entity) while the fields(columns) in the table are the attributes of the entity. If an ingredient is an important entity in your app, it deserves a table - then you can add arbitrary many ingredients (i.e. rows) to the table (not fields=columns!). It could be related to a recipe table...

Comment: Where should I add that piece of code? My goal is to create a table that has the current user as the primary key and fill in the users ingredients through a form. After I have the table with the user and user's ingredients, I want to compare the user's ingredients to another table in my database that has different recipes with their respective ingredients. I hope that makes sense... Any help would be appreciated. @Mekanik

Answer (score 0):

You are saving in a wrong manner. **ModelForm** itself gets the declared data from the form and saves them. In your case, you just need to add a user to your one-to-one field:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IngredientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Ingredients added to your account!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = IngredientForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

And add the user to your `ModelForm` field:

```
class IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ingredients
        fields = __all__
```

For the profile creation and merging with user in admin page follow my another answer which just directs that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53718908/7470786